# EA Sequence diagrams: messages font size

Tags: formatting, enterprise-architect, sequence-diagram

May this is not the right place to ask such a question, but the EA experts are welcome to take the 25 points....

I create a sequence diagram in EA and copy it to power point.
The messages font is too small for comfortable viewing.

F4 sets the lifelines font size, but how can I set the messages size?

Comment: I wondered about shape-scripts, but the messages don't have a stereotype so that's probably not possible. It would be nice to be able to apply shape scripts to object types and connector types, without needing to have a stereotype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately,as discussed, it's not possible to change the font size for message labels.

According to Sparx support, the only way to change the size of this text is using the "Tools | Options (Ctrl+F9)  | Diagram | Appearance: Configure Default Element Fonts" options. These settings will apply to **all** element and connector labels.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can.

If you right-click the label you've got some options to play around with, but font typeface and size aren't among them. You can set it bold and change the colour but that seems to be it. This applies to all connectors as far I can see, not just to sequence diagram messages.

Looking in the database I can see a set of key-value pairs in `t_connector.PDATA5` which seem to indicate that you could set italic and underline in addition to bold even though there's no way to achieve it through the GUI, but there's nothing that looks like a font size.

Answer (score 3):

You can export the diagram as EMF or WMF and post-process the labels. EA does not offer any settings for the font size.